# What is the history of the idiom 'Sick as a dog'?

Tags: phrase-origin

This phrase is often used but was intrigued to find out it's history.

Comment: ***Sick as a dog:*** ***1)*** http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-sic1.htm.    ***2)*** https://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/4/messages/934.html ***3)*** http://raivynnsroost.blogspot.com/2007/01/sick-as-dog-and-other-odd-phrases.html ***4)*** http://www.saywhydoi.com/as-sick-as-a-dog-origin/ ***5)*** https://windowthroughtime.wordpress.com/tag/origin-of-as-sick-as-a-dog/

Answer (score 1):

[1592](https://books.google.com/books?id=BeMNAAAAQAAJ&pg=RA3-PA8&dq=%22sicke+as+a+dog%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwikvf-R8ZniAhWtJzQIHUTfBjcQ6AEILDAA#v=onepage&q=%22sicke%20as%20a%20dog%22&f=false):

> A rakehell, a makeshift, a scribliug foole ;
>   A famous bayard in Citty and Schoole :
>   Now sicke as a dog, and ever braine sick,
>   Where such a rasing and desperate Dick ?

Answer (score 0):

From [OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/179187?redirectedFrom=sick%20as%20a%20dog#eid22748059) - earliest citation

> - In phrases **sick as a dog**, sick as a horse, etc.
> - **1705**   J. Vanbrugh Confederacy ii. i   If..he shou'd chance to be    fond, he'd make me as sick as a Dog.

Sick as a  dog is apparently the oldest of the  'sick as a ...'.  The poor dogs have been frequently portrayed negatively as in :  dog tired, dog in the manger, dog’s breakfast, go to the dogs.